# What does "<" do here in the expression j = i++ < 5 do?

Tags: c, operator-keyword, increment

What does the operator **<** (less-than) do?
Also, can you explain why did `for-loop` ended?

```
main()
{
   int i = 1, j = 1 ;
   for ( ; j ; printf ("%d%d\n", i,j))
   {
      j = i++ <  5 ;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

I got the output as

```
   21
   31
   41
   51
   60
```

Comment: The for loop ends when j becomes 0, i.e. when j is >= 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code checks if `i` is smaller than 5, then increments `i`. The result of the comparison is stored in `j`.

It is quite an obscure way to make a loop like this. Not very readable.

Comment: No - the post-increment happens *after* the comparison.

Comment: @BartFriederichs i came across the question on net.

Answer (score 0):

It returns `1` if `i` is less than 5, otherwise it returns `0`. Note that increment does not affect the comparison, until the next loop iteration.

Comment: Poor quality answer - what about the post-increment ?

Comment: Increment doesn't affect comparison directly.

Comment: OK - so why not mention that in your answer at least, and maybe also explain that the post-increment happens after the comparison ? SO is all about good quality questions and answers, so a terse and incomplete answer such as this is not very useful.

Comment: @Paul R: Just tried to keep answer short and clean. But you're right; that is good thing to mention.

Answer (score 0):

when your loop is executing i++ it is actually incrementing the value of i . The condition 
 j= i++ < 5  will check for the return value '1' or '0' so when accordingly your output print statement printf ("%d%d\n", i,j) will print

i=2 ; j=2<5 -> return 1  so print (2,1)
i=3; j=3<5 -> return 1 so print (3,1)

and so on till the condition becomes false and your output is finally j=return '0' for i=6

this will give you ans (6,0)